# Uncaught Error: ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, recaptcha

I am getting below mentioned error in Browser Console. I have used Contact form 7 and Google Captcha in wordpress site.

(1) Uncaught Error: ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty
(2) Uncaught error: invalid recaptcha client id: undefined

Can please assist me to fix these issues.

Answer (score 7):

Remove this from the `<head></head>`. It’s redundant.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Comment: Also loading the library twice will cause the error,so just remove the above reference from your file.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, and might be a duplicate, but this is the page I found trying to solve my problem, so I figured I'd add something towards an answer here.

I was getting the "ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty" error, and it was because the recaptcha script was being called multiple times. I was able to resolve this with a custom callback on the recaptcha's onload event:

```
var recaptchacalls = 0;

var onloadCallback = function(e) {

  grecaptcha.render('cap-' + recaptchacalls, {
    'sitekey' : '<SITE_KEY_HERE>'
  });

  recaptchacalls++;
};
```

Note the count of how many times the script is called, using that as a unique identifier for the specific container that we need to be empty.

I would venture a guess that the other error is related, non-specific identifiers in multiple calls resulting in actions being attempted on the wrong object.